# Using "WITH AS" keywords when migrating data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00928

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

If I remove the INSERT statement the SELECT works, if I have the insert Oracle complains that "missing SELECT keyword".

```
WITH tmpdata AS
(
//SOME arbitrary select statement
)

INSERT INTO myTable (someId, somevalue, someothervalue)
SELECT
 mysequence.nextval,
 tmpData.somevalue,
 tmpData.someothervalue,
FROM
 tmpdata,
 sometabletojoin
WHERE
 tmpdata.somevalue = sometabletojoin.somevaluebutintheothertable
```

Comment: Do I need to use the "CREATE TABLE something AS" syntax instead?  As seen here...

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql99_with_clause.htm

Comment: I have to ask this - you are using () around the SELECT and not {} as in your question, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (someId, somevalue, someothervalue)
WITH tmpdata AS
(
   ...
)
SELECT ...
```

Explanation: `WITH` and `SELECT` belong together; they are part of the same query. Therefore, in your example, Oracle complains about the "missing SELECT" when it reaches the (unexpected) INSERT after parsing the WITH clause.